# PHP mail() activity timeout

Tags: php, email, timeout

I want to send some mails via my programm on my own server.
I use PHP for this. Therefore I already implemented a code which works for 1-3 mails.
But it takes about 10-15 seconds for the mail to be sent. After the 3rd one I always get a timeout error "The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout".

- PHP Version 5.6.21

code I use:

```
<?php
    $sendmail = "test@myserver.com";
    $sendname = "testname";
    $receiver = "myemail@domain.com";
    $subject = "bla";
    $text = "blubb";
    mail($receiver,  $subject, $text, "From: $sendname <$sendmail>");
?>
```

sendmail and receiver is replaced.

Why does it take so much time to send one email? I planned to mail several upon on click and within seconds.

Comment: how you are going to execute it more than three time? what code you applied for that? the current code will run one time only basically. May be some other code is there which is taking time and it seems to you that mail comes late or timed-out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14481385/4248328   Or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902554/fastcgi-process-exceeded-configured-activity-timeout   Or  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8261001/4248328

Comment: I just ran with a for over this a few times

Comment: @Anant
I don't find my questions in this threads at all